# Visual studio alternatives for unity as intellisense not working

Tags: unity, c#, visual-studio, ide

I am new to unity and unity tools for game dev are unavailable in vs community,i also tried vs code.So what are some alternatives for vs for unity scripts for a beginner?

Comment: As written & titled, this is a "what tech should I use" style question which is not considered on-topic. However, asking how to get Intellisense working *would* be on topic. If fixing the problem with Visual Studio is an acceptable alternative for you, please edit the question to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure that Unity Tools for Game Dev is unavailabe in VS Community? It should come with the Unity install file but can also be found from the Visual Studio Installer.
Also it would help if you stated which version of Unity, Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code you are using.

Regardless this link shows the supported IDE's for Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptingToolsIDEs.html
According to the docs it should support Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code and Jetbrains Rider.

Though before switching your editor, are you sure that the Intellisense isn't working at all? Make sure the following are correct before proceeding:

1. Is your Visual Studio installation set as the external script editor in Unity? Check by navigating to: Edit/Preferences/External Tools/External Script Editor
2. Does your project contain a .csproj file? (You can check in the root folder of your project.)
3. Have you made your first script via the Unity Engine? I noticed when I made my first C# script outside of Unity the UnityC# project or csproj wasn't set correctly resulting in the Unity not being loaded in the project and intellisense not being available.

Comment: I am using visual studio community 2017 and unity 2018.4.And yes, vs community 2017 is set as external editor in unity.To be more clear , because intellisense was not working i trtied to figure it out and i saw that unity tools for game dev was unavailable.It had the following message:not win 10 threshold one and two build number.....So what can I do.......any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @user134855 Please open a new question where you describe your problem with visual studio in detail. Comments should not be used for follwup questions.